# How to avoid quotes when encoding a JSON object

Tags: json, haskell

I need to create something like the following JSON entity:

`{ 
    "foo": function() { *some code* }
}`

Can any of the common JSON libraries (json, jsonb, aeron etc.) easily achieve that?
I didn't find a way to tell the library not to quote the *function* part when encoding.

Thanks,

p.s. I understand the reason for not allowing such usage is to enforce correct syntax, but I'm willing to take that risk here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not a JSON entity, but a JavaScript object. [JSON](http://json.org/) has no concept of functions.

The only way to have a function encoded in JSON is indeed to encode it in a string:

```
{ "foo": "function() { return \"Hello, World\" }" }
```

When you want to execute that function in JavaScript, you'll have to [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) the string:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse('{ "foo": "function() {return \\"Hello, World\\";}" }');
var jfoo = eval('(' + jsonObj.foo + ')');
alert(jfoo()); // Shows a dialog box "Hello, World"
```

Note that this allows the source of the JSON to execute arbitrary JavaScript in the context of your website or application. Therefore, you should transfer data instead of functions whenever possible, and make sure not to `eval` code from untrusted sources.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm a newbie in JSON and JS so (as is obvious from your response) I'm not that aware of where the line between the two crosses. Still, as I'm using a JS framework to which I need to pass this sort of code - is there a Haskell package that can handle it nicely?

Comment: @Uri JSON can only represent data, JavaScript can also include code. Every haskell JSON package should be able to handle this. and output `{ "foo": "function() { return \"Hello, World\" }"}`. If you have questions about a specific haskell JSON library (`How do I encode this string with Haskell RJSON?`), you should ask another question, since this one is - despite the tag - essentially unrelated to haskell.